# Is it possible to run DocuSign SDK with an app compiled with java 8?

Tags: docusignapi, docusign-sdk

I use java 8 in my application and can not upgrade it for campatibility reasons with other applications. But DocuSign eSignature SDK is compatible with java 9 and later. So, is there any possible way to use docusign eSignature SDK with my application?

Could using an older version of docusign esign help me? Or is there any possible way to do that?

Currenlty I cannot run them beside each other. I get the error that docusign esing was compiled with a newer version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can potentially try an older version. Looking back at the older branches in https://github.com/docusign/docusign-esign-java-client, the requirement listed on some of the older branches is Java 1.7+

It looks like some users were able to use up to the SDK version 3.14 with Java 8 based on the discussion here: https://github.com/docusign/docusign-esign-java-client/issues/217